# Print to pdf using headless chrome on c# ChromeDevTools Application go in breakmode

Tags: c#, google-chrome-headless

I am trying to build an converter from HTML to PDF using Chrome print to PDF. option.

I have already try the command line program for headless Chrome but I can't add any setting, so I am  trying now to use M`asterDevs.ChromeDevTools`.

My problem is the application go in breakmode every time it passes the await, and I really don't understand what the problem could be.

```
using System;
using MasterDevs.ChromeDevTools.Protocol.Chrome.Page;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using MasterDevs.ChromeDevTools.Protocol.Chrome.DOM;
using Task = System.Threading.Tasks.Task;
using MasterDevs.ChromeDevTools;

namespace ConsoleApp4
{
    internal class Program
    {
        const int ViewPortWidth = 1440;
        const int ViewPortHeight = 900;
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Task.Run(async () =>
            {


                // STEP 1 - Run Chrome
                var chromeProcessFactory = new ChromeProcessFactory(new StubbornDirectoryCleaner());
                using (var chromeProcess = chromeProcessFactory.Create(9222, true))
                {
                    // STEP 2 - Create a debugging session
                    var sessionInfo = (await chromeProcess.GetSessionInfo()).LastOrDefault();
                    var chromeSessionFactory = new ChromeSessionFactory();
                    var chromeSession = chromeSessionFactory.Create(sessionInfo.WebSocketDebuggerUrl);

                    // STEP 3 - Send a command
                    //
                    // Here we are sending a commands to tell chrome to set the viewport size 
                    // and navigate to the specified URL
                    //await chromeSession.SendAsync(new SetDeviceMetricsOverrideCommand
                    //{
                    //    Width = ViewPortWidth,
                    //    Height = ViewPortHeight,
                    //    Scale = 1
                    //});

                    var navigateResponse = await chromeSession.SendAsync(new NavigateCommand
                    {
                        Url = "http://www.google.com"
                    });
                    Console.WriteLine("NavigateResponse: " + navigateResponse.Id);

                    var printResponse = await chromeSession.SendAsync(new PrintToPDFCommand {
                        Landscape = true
                        , DisplayHeaderFooter = true
                        , MarginBottom = 0
                        , MarginTop = 0
                        , MarginRight = 0
                        , MarginLeft = 0
                    });

                    Console.WriteLine("NavigateResponse: " + navigateResponse.Id);

                    Console.WriteLine("Exiting ..");
                }
            }).Wait();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you got the solution?

Comment: @Vaibhav Bhatia: Apparently not, but I do. See answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, let me tell you why:

You don't set the paper size or scale !

Then, the "MasterDev" doesn't correctly handle the subsequent error returned by Chrome.

Thus, the task is never set to "Error" or "Success". 
Which is why at this point, C# awaits the answer ad-infinitum.

Guess how I know ? 
1.5 year ago, I was debugging for an hour when I had the same problem  ;)

Here's the issue with a bugfix proposal:
https://github.com/MasterDevs/ChromeDevTools/issues/37

```
Dim cm2inch As UnitConversion_t = Function(ByVal centimeters As Double) centimeters * 0.393701
Dim mm2inch As UnitConversion_t = Function(ByVal milimeters As Double) milimeters * 0.0393701

Dim printCommand2 As PrintToPDFCommand = New PrintToPDFCommand() With {
    .Scale = 1,
    .MarginTop = 0,
    .MarginLeft = 0,
    .MarginRight = 0,
    .MarginBottom = 0,
    .PrintBackground = True,
    .Landscape = False,
    .PaperWidth = mm2inch(conversionData.PageWidth),
    .PaperHeight = mm2inch(conversionData.PageHeight) ' 
}
```

See also
[How to receive the height of DOM element when printing with wkhtmltopdf library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64366302/how-to-receive-the-height-of-dom-element-when-printing-with-wkhtmltopdf-library/64367086#64367086)