# How to receive the height of DOM element when printing with wkhtmltopdf library?

Tags: javascript, wkhtmltopdf

When I try to get offsetHeight or of any DOM element with Javascript when printing with wkhtmltopdf library, the height is never determined and is always equal to 0. When I execute the same JS code in any browser it works correctly and results in a specific height of element.

I googled for a long time and I found out that it might be related with wkhtmltopdf in which the width and height of document and window are equal to 0. I tried to override the size of the body tag with CSS and override the viewport size with wkhtmltopdf configuration parameters, but the offsetHeight still results in 0.

Is there any known walkaround to receive height of DOM element when printing with wkhtmltopdf?

I use the latest stable version of the printing library (0.12.6)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used wkHtml2Pdf in the past.
My advice is to stop right now, because wkhtmltopdf uses a very old browser version, and you're likely to run into problems anyway. Also, wkHtmlToPdf doesn't work properly (and performance is crap).

Instead, you can use a much better option. 
That option is to use the Chrome DevTools with the remote-debugging-protocol:
https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/

Which basically runs Chrome like this

```
chrome.exe --remote-debugging-port=9222
```

With optional

```
$"--user-data-dir=\"{directoryInfo.FullName}\"";
```

and

```
"--headless --disable-gpu";
```

Here's how I start the Chrome process on the server (C# Code)

```
public IChromeProcess Create(int port, bool headless)
{
    string path = System.IO.Path.GetRandomFileName();
    System.IO.DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(
        System.IO.Path.Combine(
            System.IO.Path.GetTempPath(), path)
    );

    string remoteDebuggingArg = $"--remote-debugging-port={port}";
    string userDirectoryArg = $"--user-data-dir=\"{directoryInfo.FullName}\"";
    const string headlessArg = "--headless --disable-gpu";

    // https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/
    System.Collections.Generic.List<string> chromeProcessArgs = 
        new System.Collections.Generic.List<string>
    {
        remoteDebuggingArg,
        userDirectoryArg,
        // Indicates that the browser is in "browse without sign-in" (Guest session) mode. 
        // Should completely disable extensions, sync and bookmarks.
        "--bwsi", 
        "--no-first-run"
    };


    if (false)
    {
        string proxyProtocol = "socks5";
        proxyProtocol = "http";
        proxyProtocol = "https";
        string proxyIP = "68.183.233.181";
        string proxyPort = "3128";
        string proxyArg = "--proxy-server=\"" + proxyProtocol + "://" + proxyIP + ":" + proxyPort + "\"";
        chromeProcessArgs.Add(proxyArg);
    }


    if (headless)
        chromeProcessArgs.Add(headlessArg);

    if(IsRoot)
        chromeProcessArgs.Add("--no-sandbox");

    string args = string.Join(" ", chromeProcessArgs);
    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(ChromePath, args);
    System.Diagnostics.Process chromeProcess = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(processStartInfo);

    string remoteDebuggingUrl = "http://localhost:" + port;
    return new LocalChromeProcess(new System.Uri(remoteDebuggingUrl), () => DirectoryCleaner.Delete(directoryInfo), chromeProcess);
}
```

I used this C# library here to interface with the DevTools (via WebSockets):
https://github.com/MasterDevs/ChromeDevTools

If you use NodeJS on the server, you could use this:
https://github.com/cyrus-and/chrome-remote-interface
or for TypeScript:
https://github.com/TracerBench/chrome-debugging-client

In order to generate a PDF, you need to issue the PrintToPDF-Command:

```
Dim cm2inch As UnitConversion_t = Function(ByVal centimeters As Double) centimeters * 0.393701
Dim mm2inch As UnitConversion_t = Function(ByVal milimeters As Double) milimeters * 0.0393701

Dim printCommand2 As PrintToPDFCommand = New PrintToPDFCommand() With {
    .Scale = 1,
    .MarginTop = 0,
    .MarginLeft = 0,
    .MarginRight = 0,
    .MarginBottom = 0,
    .PrintBackground = True,
    .Landscape = False,
    .PaperWidth = mm2inch(conversionData.PageWidth),
    .PaperHeight = mm2inch(conversionData.PageHeight) ' 
}
```

And to create a raster graphic, you need to issue the CaptureScreenshot-Command :

```
Dim screenshot As MasterDevs.ChromeDevTools.CommandResponse(Of CaptureScreenshotCommandResponse) = Await chromeSession.SendAsync(New CaptureScreenshotCommand With {
    .Format = "png"
})
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Screenshot taken.")
conversionData.PngData = System.Convert.FromBase64String(screenshot.Result.Data)
```

Note that for the screenshot to work properly, you need to set the width and the height via the SetDeviceMetricsOverride-Command:

```
Await chromeSession.SendAsync(New SetDeviceMetricsOverrideCommand With {
    .Width = conversionData.ViewPortWidth,
    .Height = conversionData.ViewPortHeight,
    .Scale = 1
})
```

You might have to put overflow:hidden on the HTML, or some sub-elements just so you don't screenshot the scrollbars ;)

By the way, if you need a specific version of Chrome for Windows (Chromium, because old Chrome versions are not available for security reasons), you can get them from the Chocolatey-Repository:
https://chocolatey.org/packages/chromium/#versionhistory

Here's my full test-code for reference (minus some classes)

```
Imports MasterDevs.ChromeDevTools
Imports MasterDevs.ChromeDevTools.Protocol.Chrome.Browser
Imports MasterDevs.ChromeDevTools.Protocol.Chrome.Page
Imports MasterDevs.ChromeDevTools.Protocol.Chrome.Target

Namespace Portal_Convert.CdpConverter


    Public Class ChromiumBasedConverter


        Private Delegate Function UnitConversion_t(ByVal value As Double) As Double




        Public Shared Sub KillHeadlessChromes(ByVal writer As System.IO.TextWriter)
            Dim allProcesses As System.Diagnostics.Process() = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses()
            Dim exeName As String = "\chrome.exe"

            If System.Environment.OSVersion.Platform = System.PlatformID.Unix Then
                exeName = "/chrome"
            End If

            For i As Integer = 0 To allProcesses.Length - 1
                Dim proc As System.Diagnostics.Process = allProcesses(i)
                Dim commandLine As String = ProcessUtils.GetCommandLine(proc)
                If String.IsNullOrEmpty(commandLine) Then Continue For
                commandLine = commandLine.ToLowerInvariant()
                If commandLine.IndexOf(exeName, System.StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) = -1 Then Continue For

                If commandLine.IndexOf("--headless", System.StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) <> -1 Then
                    writer.WriteLine($"Killing process {proc.Id} with command line ""{commandLine}""")
                    ProcessUtils.KillProcessAndChildren(proc.Id)
                End If
            Next

            writer.WriteLine($"Finished killing headless chromes")
        End Sub


        Public Shared Sub KillHeadlessChromes()
            KillHeadlessChromes(System.Console.Out)
        End Sub


        Private Shared Function __Assign(Of T)(ByRef target As T, value As T) As T
            target = value
            Return value
        End Function


        Public Shared Function KillHeadlessChromesWeb() As System.Collections.Generic.List(Of String)
            Dim ls As System.Collections.Generic.List(Of String) = New System.Collections.Generic.List(Of String)()
            Dim sb As System.Text.StringBuilder = New System.Text.StringBuilder()

            Using sw As System.IO.StringWriter = New System.IO.StringWriter(sb)
                KillHeadlessChromes(sw)
            End Using

            Using tr As System.IO.TextReader = New System.IO.StringReader(sb.ToString())
                Dim thisLine As String = Nothing

                While (__Assign(thisLine, tr.ReadLine())) IsNot Nothing
                    ls.Add(thisLine)
                End While
            End Using

            sb.Length = 0
            sb = Nothing
            Return ls
        End Function


        Private Shared Async Function InternalConnect(ByVal ci As ConnectionInfo, ByVal remoteDebuggingUri As String) As System.Threading.Tasks.Task
            ci.ChromeProcess = New RemoteChromeProcess(remoteDebuggingUri)
            ci.SessionInfo = Await ci.ChromeProcess.StartNewSession()
        End Function


        Private Shared Async Function ConnectToChrome(ByVal chromePath As String, ByVal remoteDebuggingUri As String) As System.Threading.Tasks.Task(Of ConnectionInfo)
            Dim ci As ConnectionInfo = New ConnectionInfo()

            Try
                Await InternalConnect(ci, remoteDebuggingUri)
            Catch ex As System.Exception

                If ex.InnerException IsNot Nothing AndAlso Object.ReferenceEquals(ex.InnerException.[GetType](), GetType(System.Net.WebException)) Then

                    If (CType(ex.InnerException, System.Net.WebException)).Status = System.Net.WebExceptionStatus.ConnectFailure Then
                        Dim chromeProcessFactory As MasterDevs.ChromeDevTools.IChromeProcessFactory = New MasterDevs.ChromeDevTools.ChromeProcessFactory(New FastStubbornDirectoryCleaner(), chromePath)
                        Dim persistentChromeProcess As MasterDevs.ChromeDevTools.IChromeProcess = chromeProcessFactory.Create(9222, True)

                        ' await cannot be used inside catch ...
                        ' Await InternalConnect(ci, remoteDebuggingUri)
                        InternalConnect(ci, remoteDebuggingUri).Wait()
                        Return ci
                    End If
                End If

                System.Console.WriteLine(chromePath)
                System.Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
                System.Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace)

                If ex.InnerException IsNot Nothing Then
                    System.Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException.Message)
                    System.Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException.StackTrace)
                End If

                System.Console.WriteLine(ex.[GetType]().FullName)
                Throw
            End Try

            Return ci
        End Function


        Private Shared Async Function ClosePage(ByVal chromeSession As MasterDevs.ChromeDevTools.IChromeSession, ByVal frameId As String, ByVal headLess As Boolean) As System.Threading.Tasks.Task
            Dim closeTargetTask As System.Threading.Tasks.Task(Of MasterDevs.ChromeDevTools.CommandResponse(Of CloseTargetCommandResponse)) = chromeSession.SendAsync(New CloseTargetCommand() With {
                .TargetId = frameId
            })

            ' await will block forever if headless    
            If Not headLess Then
                Dim closeTargetResponse As MasterDevs.ChromeDevTools.CommandResponse(Of CloseTargetCommandResponse) = Await closeTargetTask
                System.Console.WriteLine(closeTargetResponse)
            Else
                System.Console.WriteLine(closeTargetTask)
            End If
        End Function


        Public Shared Async Function ConvertDataAsync(ByVal conversionData As ConversionData) As System.Threading.Tasks.Task
            Dim chromeSessionFactory As MasterDevs.ChromeDevTools.IChromeSessionFactory = New MasterDevs.ChromeDevTools.ChromeSessionFactory()


            Using connectionInfo As ConnectionInfo = Await ConnectToChrome(conversionData.ChromePath, conversionData.RemoteDebuggingUri)
                Dim chromeSession As MasterDevs.ChromeDevTools.IChromeSession = chromeSessionFactory.Create(connectionInfo.SessionInfo.WebSocketDebuggerUrl)

                Await chromeSession.SendAsync(New SetDeviceMetricsOverrideCommand With {
                    .Width = conversionData.ViewPortWidth,
                    .Height = conversionData.ViewPortHeight,
                    .Scale = 1
                })

                Dim navigateResponse As MasterDevs.ChromeDevTools.CommandResponse(Of NavigateCommandResponse) = Await chromeSession.SendAsync(New NavigateCommand With {
                    .Url = "about:blank"
                })

                System.Console.WriteLine("NavigateResponse: " & navigateResponse.Id)
                Dim setContentResponse As MasterDevs.ChromeDevTools.CommandResponse(Of SetDocumentContentCommandResponse) = Await chromeSession.SendAsync(New SetDocumentContentCommand() With {
                    .FrameId = navigateResponse.Result.FrameId,
                    .Html = conversionData.Html
                })

                Dim cm2inch As UnitConversion_t = Function(ByVal centimeters As Double) centimeters * 0.393701
                Dim mm2inch As UnitConversion_t = Function(ByVal milimeters As Double) milimeters * 0.0393701

                Dim printCommand2 As PrintToPDFCommand = New PrintToPDFCommand() With {
                    .Scale = 1,
                    .MarginTop = 0,
                    .MarginLeft = 0,
                    .MarginRight = 0,
                    .MarginBottom = 0,
                    .PrintBackground = True,
                    .Landscape = False,
                    .PaperWidth = mm2inch(conversionData.PageWidth),
                    .PaperHeight = mm2inch(conversionData.PageHeight) ' 
                }

                '.PaperWidth = cm2inch(conversionData.PageWidth),
                '.PaperHeight = cm2inch(conversionData.PageHeight)


                If conversionData.ChromiumActions.HasFlag(ChromiumActions_t.GetVersion) Then

                    Try
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Getting browser-version")
                        Dim version As MasterDevs.ChromeDevTools.CommandResponse(Of GetVersionCommandResponse) = Await chromeSession.SendAsync(New GetVersionCommand())
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Got browser-version")
                        conversionData.Version = version.Result
                    Catch ex As System.Exception
                        conversionData.Exception = ex
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message)
                    End Try
                End If

                If conversionData.ChromiumActions.HasFlag(ChromiumActions_t.ConvertToImage) Then

                    Try
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Taking screenshot")
                        Dim screenshot As MasterDevs.ChromeDevTools.CommandResponse(Of CaptureScreenshotCommandResponse) = Await chromeSession.SendAsync(New CaptureScreenshotCommand With {
                            .Format = "png"
                        })
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Screenshot taken.")
                        conversionData.PngData = System.Convert.FromBase64String(screenshot.Result.Data)
                    Catch ex As System.Exception
                        conversionData.Exception = ex
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message)
                    End Try
                End If

                If conversionData.ChromiumActions.HasFlag(ChromiumActions_t.ConvertToPdf) Then

                    Try
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Printing PDF")
                        Dim pdf As MasterDevs.ChromeDevTools.CommandResponse(Of PrintToPDFCommandResponse) = Await chromeSession.SendAsync(printCommand2)
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("PDF printed.")
                        conversionData.PdfData = System.Convert.FromBase64String(pdf.Result.Data)
                    Catch ex As System.Exception
                        conversionData.Exception = ex
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message)
                    End Try
                End If


                System.Console.WriteLine("Closing page")
                Await ClosePage(chromeSession, navigateResponse.Result.FrameId, True)
                System.Console.WriteLine("Page closed")

            End Using ' connectionInfo

        End Function ' ConvertDataAsync


        Public Shared Sub ConvertData(ByVal conversionData As ConversionData)
            ConvertDataAsync(conversionData).Wait()
        End Sub


    End Class


End Namespace
```

Note that if anyone is using C#, it's better to use this library:
https://github.com/BaristaLabs/chrome-dev-tools-runtime
which uses less external depencencies, and is NetCore. I used the other only because I had to backport it to an old framework version...

Comment: Stefan Steiger, Thank you for your answer. I decided to use the https://github.com/Sicos1977/ChromeHtmlToPdf library instead, because BaristaLabs' tool seems to not be developed in the recent time. It is based on .NET Core as well.